# How to add a drop down menu on Actionbar without the preselected item occupying space

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I would like to add on the android Actionbar a drop down menu without a preselected option. More precisely I would like the arrow to be next to the application's icon on actionbar. So far the code is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .
    .
    .
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
             SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.logo_options,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(spinnerAdapter, null);

    }
```

How can I get rid of the text on the actionbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a popup menu which drops down whenever you click on action bar button:

```
 View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.apps);
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popupMenu.getMenu());

                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.windowitem1)
                            //Do whatever you want to
                        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.windowitem2)
                            //Do whatever you want to
                        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.windowitem3)
                            //Do whatever you want to

                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
```

ActionBar text can be removed by  android:showAsAction="" property,you can set it accordingly.....